# One-to-one relationship typeorm, save or update

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, one-to-one

I am trying to implement a one-to-one relationship with `nestjs`, `typeorm` and `postgres`.

I have a Profile Entity

```js
  @OneToOne(() => Trainer, trainer => trainer.profile)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'trainer_trainer_id' })
  trainer!: Trainer;
```

and a Trainer Entity

```js
  @OneToOne(() => Profile, profile => profile.trainer)
  profile!: Profile;
```

When the user submits to become Trainer, I would like to update the database with a new row in the `trainer` table and add the associated id in the `profile` table.

So in the trainer repository I do:

```js
  const trainer = CreateTrainerDto.toEntity(createTrainerDto);
    trainer.profile = profile;
    return await trainer.save();
```

this works well but it creates a new row in the `trainer` table every time (and updates accordingly the id in the `profile` table). but I was expecting `save()` to update an existing row if a trainer was already saved.

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The save method have two functionalities, insert and update.

If the provided entity instance have an id value it, update will  execute, else insert.

Therefore, you can do the following:

```js
const trainer = await this.trainerRepository.findOne(id) || this.trainerRepository.create(); // you can add the "or create" to have both create and update functionalities in one method
return await this.trainerRepository.save({...trainer, ...createTrainerDto, profile})
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call the save function on an entity, two things can happen:

- If id is not set in the provided object, TypeORM will insert a new row in this table.
- If id is set in the object, TypeORM will update the row corresponding to the referenced entity id.

Since your DTO is called createTrainerDto I assume you are not providing the id of the entity. This code will therefore always insert a new row in the table.

Create your DTOs so that the id property is optional, this way you can use the DTO for both creating and updating. For example:

```js
export class TrainerDTO {
    id?: number;

    name: string;

    profile: ProfileDTO;
}
```

Comment: Also, important to note that if you have a OneToOne relationship between two entities and there is already an existing record, the functionality of inserting a new row with save function won't happen